# Gunicorn multiple flask workers and bound tasks celery

Tags: python, flask, celery, gunicorn

Following [this guide](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask)(*Complex Example: Showing Status Updates and Results* section) i have 2 flask endpoints for starting a bound task (POST request) and retreiving tasks result by its id (GET request to /status/<task_id>).

Running flask app as `flask run` in one shell and `celery worker -A app.celery -l info` in another one, it is possible to run task and then get its result by GET request to the /status/ endpoint.

After adding gunicorn and setting number of workers to 3, POST requests run normally, but getting status of a specific running task is a problem, as it can't get task(task.info is None). There is a chance of getting task result by this status endpoint, but if i correctrly understand the problem, it depends on which flask instance gunicorn redirects a request to.

I dont set any specific celery setting, only broker and result_backend(using RabbitMQ).

How to correctly configure the gunicorn+flask+celery for this sort of tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using redis as result backend(or any other than RPC, i believe).

According to the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#states)

> The RPC result backend (rpc://) is special as it doesn’t actually store the states, but rather sends them as messages. This is an important difference as it means that a result can only be retrieved once, and only by the client that initiated the task. Two different processes can’t wait for the same result.